# Undefined variable in loop

Tags: php

I create each

```
    $categories = array();


    $crawler
        ->filter('.am-filter-items-attr_category_ids')
        ->each(function ($node) use ($client) {

            $node->filter('ul > li ')->each(function ($level2) {
           
               $name_one = $level2->text();

                $level2->filter(' ul > li > a')->each(function ($level3) {
                     
                     $href = $level2->extract(array('href'));

                     $categories[] = array('cat' => $href[0],
                     'Cat_name' => $name_one);
              }
           }
       }
```

and I get a error `Undefined variable: name_one`

I need to create an array, how do I pass a variable inside another loop? So that there are no mistakes?

Comment: Add `use ($name_one)` like you did in the function above (`use ($client)`)

Comment: oh really thanks, I really didn’t notice something, I don’t feel smart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add this variable to last function.
Change `->each(function ($level3) {` to `->each(function ($level3) use ($name_one) {`

Comment: oh really thanks, I really didn’t notice something, I don’t feel smart